# Converting from hex to base64

Tags: python, python-3.x, cryptography, base64

I have been tasked to take a hex text and convert it base64 system. My problem is I am getting an incorrect output from my code.

**Input given:**

> 49276d206b696c6c696e6720796f757220627261696e206c696b65206120706f69736f6e6f7573206d757368726f6f6d

**Output expected:**

> SSdtIGtpbGxpbmcgeW91ciBicmFpbiBsaWtlIGEgcG9pc29ub3VzIG11c2hyb29t

**Output from my program:**

> kk7aga2lY2NL5nIHLe6uiBicMLS3IGxp1spAhIHBe0ub9ub3rmQNXVzaOTe3

**How I expect my code to work :**

*NOTE:* *I understand that Python has built in ways to convert something to base64, as well as using int() to convert any base to decimal, I have opted to use my own as a way to understand the problem more.*

1. Take a string of hexadecimal text and convert it to a decimal number.
2. Convert the decimal number to a binary number.
3. Separate the binary number into chunks of 24 bits.
4. Split the chunk of 24 bits into 4 sections of 6 bits each.
5. Convert each 6 bits into a decimal number.
6. Convert the decimal number into the base64-encoded letter/number. Starting from "A" (index of 0) to "/" (index of 63)

**My code:**

```
def convertToDecimal(text, original_base):
    '''
    Program assumes user is using it correctly. It does not bother checking for weird cases like a base being 0 or a negative.
    '''

    decimal = 0  # used for converting to decimal base first
    exp = len(text) - 1  # starting exponent of the base (8^1, 8^0, etc)

    hex_nums = {"a": 10, "b": 11, "c": 12, "d": 13, "e": 14, "f": 15}

    # convert original_base to a decimal number
    for val in text:
        if val in hex_nums:  # have to worry about letters
            val = hex_nums[val]
        decimal += int(val) * (original_base ** exp)
        exp -= 1

    return decimal


def base64(text, base):
    letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/"

    bin_num = bin(convertToDecimal(text, base))[2:]

    base64_val = ""

    # used for indexing each chunk of binary values
    i = 0
    j = 25

    # used for each chunk of six bits to be converted into a number
    six_bit_chunk = ""

    while True:
        if j > len(bin_num):
            # prevents index out of bounds error
            break

        bin_chunk = bin_num[i:j]  # take a chunk of 24 bits
        for x in range(0, 24, 6):
            six_bit_chunk += bin_chunk[x:x + 6]  # take a smaller chunk of 6 bits
            index = convertToDecimal(six_bit_chunk, 2)  # use the 6 bits to create a decimal value from 0-63
            base64_val += letters[index]
            six_bit_chunk = ""

        i += 25
        j += 25

    return base64_val


new_text = base64("49276d206b696c6c696e6720796f757220627261696e206c696b65206120706f69736f6e6f7573206d757368726f6f6d",
                  16)

print(new_text)
```

My attempts to solve this problem have been to look at what the chunks of six bits produce, and they are creating the correct decimal number and the correct letter/number in base64.

Comment: You conversion scheme doesn't preserve the original length in bytes. So while you can convert to decimal, that is not enough. When you convert this to a bit string you need to pad the string *on the left* with enough 0 bits to make it exactly 8 * L bits long, where L is the number of bytes in the original hex string. Also, `i` and `j` should increment by 24, not 25, and I'm not sure what is happening at the end of the bit string.

Comment: Do you have other sample inputs and expected outputs to test?

Comment: FTR: This is the first [cryptopals challenge](https://cryptopals.com/). In the future you may want to mention that. It'll encourage people to nudge you in the right direction instead of giving the answer directly, increasing the learning effect. Good look and have fun!

Comment: Why are you going from hex to base 10 to binary?  It is easier to go directly from hex to binary.  Two hex digits converts directly to eight bits: 0xAF -> 0b10101111.  Hint 24 bits is 6 hex digits.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if this is correct, but with a few changes I achieved that the output of the function matches the expected output you provided.

The changes (also taking into account the comment from user @JamesKPolt):

- everywhere you had 25 y used 24 instead
- add zero padding to the beginning of `bin_num` to complete the length to a multiple of 24

The modified code:

```
def base64(text, base):
    letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/"

    bin_num = bin(convertToDecimal(text, base))[2:]

    # pad with zeros to the left to get multiple of 24
    remainder = divmod(len(bin_num), 24)[1]
    if remainder > 0:
        additional_zeros = 24 - remainder
        bin_num = ('0' * additional_zeros) + bin_num

    base64_val = ""

    # used for indexing each chunk of binary values
    i = 0
    j = 24

    # used for each chunk of six bits to be converted into a number
    six_bit_chunk = ""

    while True:
        if j > len(bin_num):
            # prevents index out of bounds error
            break

        bin_chunk = bin_num[i:j]  # take a chunk of 24 bits
        for x in range(0, 24, 6):
            six_bit_chunk += bin_chunk[x:x + 6]  # take a smaller chunk of 6 bits
            index = convertToDecimal(six_bit_chunk, 2)  # use the 6 bits to create a decimal value from 0-63
            base64_val += letters[index]
            six_bit_chunk = ""

        i += 24
        j += 24

    return base64_val
```

This modified function passes all of the following test cases:

```
sample_data = [
    (
        '49276d206b696c6c696e6720796f757220627261696e206c696b65206120706f69736f6e6f7573206d757368726f6f6d',
        'SSdtIGtpbGxpbmcgeW91ciBicmFpbiBsaWtlIGEgcG9pc29ub3VzIG11c2hyb29t',
    ),
    (
        '24e1f218372064987d5457b639819715bddb51558cc4acb3ce6eeacd7afa2751bac0a5c7c3c636f24babff4ad68473db',
        'JOHyGDcgZJh9VFe2OYGXFb3bUVWMxKyzzm7qzXr6J1G6wKXHw8Y28kur/0rWhHPb',
    ),
    (
        '79d6e3a9d5bfba9902274e1b1c2d956fa92d16ba9a972825eb0b32aecd2401653624f900fe79b4550c24aae136ae7260',
        'edbjqdW/upkCJ04bHC2Vb6ktFrqalygl6wsyrs0kAWU2JPkA/nm0VQwkquE2rnJg',
    ),
    (
        'd251b89c473d6336dfeb3714d92c6b2080c863624ca2746e1380bd0642893ba64ebdae23bb7ad9a1f3ad9efbdc2f18e6',
        '0lG4nEc9Yzbf6zcU2SxrIIDIY2JMonRuE4C9BkKJO6ZOva4ju3rZofOtnvvcLxjm',
    ),
    (
        '5c2b578064178ad329f37041b063ec05c3ce8f202bb44e9a1260c6ded11ddd91d25ac83bba31bac7987e2da3a188c23d',
        'XCtXgGQXitMp83BBsGPsBcPOjyArtE6aEmDG3tEd3ZHSWsg7ujG6x5h+LaOhiMI9',
    ),
    (
        '018b79f5c3c1a4f59d12cda25c5ca2a29c4c1fdd1cfdf3f0a4faf350fe384d21bcfd83a8350b49231cf8536595f2a43a',
        'AYt59cPBpPWdEs2iXFyiopxMH90c/fPwpPrzUP44TSG8/YOoNQtJIxz4U2WV8qQ6',
    ),
    (
        'a617cfbe469cecd19f5ac75303a3049319ffb03d9a757c690d7c09d94dbabd6dce2314e1f409e6285fc0a0220eb803fe',
        'phfPvkac7NGfWsdTA6MEkxn/sD2adXxpDXwJ2U26vW3OIxTh9AnmKF/AoCIOuAP+',
    ),
    (
        '2bc40041dbe6937e1113b191fd136bcdd741169e9e81809e83ad3104d447d700ed9d1ab5cfbc113c0731b855fde98f87',
        'K8QAQdvmk34RE7GR/RNrzddBFp6egYCeg60xBNRH1wDtnRq1z7wRPAcxuFX96Y+H',
    ),
    (
        '1904435f5964861c5284b08e0ebf3d201da3ec795a3d9b0f7d5056c4369daed59d42cac72c897356a46305f7aac5fcb4',
        'GQRDX1lkhhxShLCODr89IB2j7HlaPZsPfVBWxDadrtWdQsrHLIlzVqRjBfeqxfy0',
    ),
]

for i, (input_str, expected_output) in enumerate(sample_data):
    print('i              ', i)
    print('input_str      ', input_str)
    print('expected_output', expected_output)

    function_output = base64(input_str, 16)
    print('function_output', function_output)
    assert expected_output == function_output
```

Comment: I would need more sample inputs and expected outputs to test the correctness of my modifications.

Comment: @Peter corrected my answer using the sample data you provided

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just iterate over the binary representation in groups of 6 directly instead of grouping by 24 and separating into 4 groups again?

But it still has to be left-padded with zeros to a multiple of 24 before splitting into groups of 6.

My function:

```
def base64_v2(text, base):
    base64_letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/"
    n1 = 24
    n2 = 6

    dec_num = int(text, base)
    bin_str = bin(dec_num)[2:]

    # pad with zeros to the left to get multiple of 'n1'
    remainder = divmod(len(bin_str), n1)[1]
    if remainder > 0:
        additional_zeros = n1 - remainder
        bin_str = ('0' * additional_zeros) + bin_str

    return ''.join(
        base64_letters[int(bin_str[i:i+n2], 2)]
        for i in range(0, len(bin_str), n2))
```

My function passes all the following test cases:

```
sample_data = [
    (
        '49276d206b696c6c696e6720796f757220627261696e206c696b65206120706f69736f6e6f7573206d757368726f6f6d',
        'SSdtIGtpbGxpbmcgeW91ciBicmFpbiBsaWtlIGEgcG9pc29ub3VzIG11c2hyb29t',
    ),
    (
        '24e1f218372064987d5457b639819715bddb51558cc4acb3ce6eeacd7afa2751bac0a5c7c3c636f24babff4ad68473db',
        'JOHyGDcgZJh9VFe2OYGXFb3bUVWMxKyzzm7qzXr6J1G6wKXHw8Y28kur/0rWhHPb',
    ),
    (
        '79d6e3a9d5bfba9902274e1b1c2d956fa92d16ba9a972825eb0b32aecd2401653624f900fe79b4550c24aae136ae7260',
        'edbjqdW/upkCJ04bHC2Vb6ktFrqalygl6wsyrs0kAWU2JPkA/nm0VQwkquE2rnJg',
    ),
    (
        'd251b89c473d6336dfeb3714d92c6b2080c863624ca2746e1380bd0642893ba64ebdae23bb7ad9a1f3ad9efbdc2f18e6',
        '0lG4nEc9Yzbf6zcU2SxrIIDIY2JMonRuE4C9BkKJO6ZOva4ju3rZofOtnvvcLxjm',
    ),
    (
        '5c2b578064178ad329f37041b063ec05c3ce8f202bb44e9a1260c6ded11ddd91d25ac83bba31bac7987e2da3a188c23d',
        'XCtXgGQXitMp83BBsGPsBcPOjyArtE6aEmDG3tEd3ZHSWsg7ujG6x5h+LaOhiMI9',
    ),
    (
        '018b79f5c3c1a4f59d12cda25c5ca2a29c4c1fdd1cfdf3f0a4faf350fe384d21bcfd83a8350b49231cf8536595f2a43a',
        'AYt59cPBpPWdEs2iXFyiopxMH90c/fPwpPrzUP44TSG8/YOoNQtJIxz4U2WV8qQ6',
    ),
    (
        'a617cfbe469cecd19f5ac75303a3049319ffb03d9a757c690d7c09d94dbabd6dce2314e1f409e6285fc0a0220eb803fe',
        'phfPvkac7NGfWsdTA6MEkxn/sD2adXxpDXwJ2U26vW3OIxTh9AnmKF/AoCIOuAP+',
    ),
    (
        '2bc40041dbe6937e1113b191fd136bcdd741169e9e81809e83ad3104d447d700ed9d1ab5cfbc113c0731b855fde98f87',
        'K8QAQdvmk34RE7GR/RNrzddBFp6egYCeg60xBNRH1wDtnRq1z7wRPAcxuFX96Y+H',
    ),
    (
        '1904435f5964861c5284b08e0ebf3d201da3ec795a3d9b0f7d5056c4369daed59d42cac72c897356a46305f7aac5fcb4',
        'GQRDX1lkhhxShLCODr89IB2j7HlaPZsPfVBWxDadrtWdQsrHLIlzVqRjBfeqxfy0',
    ),
]

for i, (input_str, expected_output) in enumerate(sample_data):
    print('i              ', i)
    print('input_str      ', input_str)
    print('expected_output', expected_output)

    function_output = base64_v2(input_str, 16)
    print('function_output', function_output)
    assert expected_output == function_output
```